# Javascript in the search box

Tags: javascript, html

I have in html javascript that shows me today's date and a search box. I try to create html so that the current date is always prescribed in the search box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Titel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
                 <script>           var datum = new Date(); // aktuální datum
                var retezec = ""; // postupně se k němu budou přičítat další řetězce
                retezec += datum.getDate() + ". "; // Den v měsíci
                retezec += (1 + datum.getMonth()) + ". "; // Měsíce jsou číslovány od nuly
                document.write( retezec ); // Výpis řetězce do dokumentu</script>

 <a href="https://translate.google.com/">
    <img class="logo-search" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="position: absolute; left:45%" width="10%" height="10%"></a>
    <form class="search-form" method="get" action="https://translate.google.com/" target="_top"; style="position: absolute; left:250pt; top: 30%">
        <input type="text" value = retezec name="q" class="search-bar" style="font-size: 30pt; width: 150%; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">
    </form>
    

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't want "document.write", you want to set the value of the input element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the value of the search input also run the script after the DOM creation.

I modified your script, so you can have a better understanding.

- set an ID on the input, so we can target that input from the script.
- write the script before the closing tag of the body, so script can
  run after all the DOM elements are created.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Titel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
                 

       <a href="https://translate.google.com/">
          <img class="logo-search" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="position: absolute; left:45%" width="10%" height="10%">
       </a>
       <form  class="search-form" method="get" action="https://translate.google.com/" target="_top"; style="position: absolute; left:250pt; top: 30%">
          <input id="search-box" type="text" name="q" class="search-bar" style="font-size: 30pt; width: 150%; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">
       </form>
    
       <script>
         var datum = new Date(); // aktuální datum
         var retezec = ""; // postupně se k němu budou přičítat další řetězce
         retezec += datum.getDate() + ". "; // Den v měsíci
         retezec += (1 + datum.getMonth()) + ". "; // Měsíce jsou číslovány od nuly
         document.getElementById('search-box').value = retezec;
       </script>
     </body>
```